# Zoom icon too large and blurry in system tray

Tags: 20.04, icons, system-tray, budgie, zoom-meeting

I installed Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 and the Zoom application icon appears  too large and blurry on the tray, as shown on the attached screenshot. It does not follow the resizing of all other icons, which causes the top of maximized windows to be hidden.

[image: Screenshot of Ubuntu Budgie system tray]

None of the similar questions I could find provided any hint to a solution.

Any idea on why this icon behaves differently? How to change it so it resizes appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Forticlient VPN and found a workaround for it: find the image in the installation directory of your application and resize it to a smaller size, e.g. using nomacs.

In my case, I resized the original icon size of 42x42 to 16x16, which was a bit too small though. It seems that 20x20 could be fine.

The above is a workaround, but at least it prevents overlapping of the top panel over fullscreen window controls.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I had tried to do it, but since this is a snap application the file system is read-only. So even if I copied the icons and resized them, I cannot get them on the right location.
When trying "sudo cp ~/ZoomSnapIcons/resized/* /snap/zoom-client/current/usr/share/pixmaps/" I get the message "cp: cannot create regular file './application-x-zoom.png': Read-only file system"
Is there an easy way around?

Comment: That's the way snaps are supposed to work (confinement). Although likely possible, in such cases I would just use the deb package.

Comment: I have the same issue. Where can I find the installation directory of an application?

Comment: @Alejandro Try the _whereis_ command or have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340281/where-is-ubuntu-storing-installed-programs).